# How can 'admin_email' be set?

Tags: admin, email

Where is the value for `admin_email` set?

```
$email = get_option('admin_email');
```

How can I change it?

Answer (score 6):

In Wordpress backend go to: **Settings > General** and the field **'Email Address'**.

Or in php: update_option('admin_email', 'your_email@abc.com');
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option

Answer (score 1):

As of 4.9 there is a requirement the user send an outbound email in order to change the admin email from the backend. If you can't send outbound email, you can't change the email without custom code. This plugin restores functionality to pre-4.9:

[Change Admin Email](https://wordpress.org/plugins/change-admin-email-setting-without-outbound-email/)